# I am extracting data from an external URL and unable to get the javascript functions working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url

I want to load the external page's data into a div along with the javascript functions(though the js file is same for both of them, the functions do not work). The file loads fine into the page, but the javascript function don't work properly.
My Code-

```
var emaild = $("#hidden").val(); 
var div = $("#mydiv");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $.getScript("js.js", function() {
      div.html($("#load").load('posts.php?id='+emaild));
});
   }, 6000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Thanks in advance. Hope I get a solution soon! :D

Comment: Or you referring to *your* javascript or the javascripts of the page you load?

Comment: Are there any errors on the page?  What debugging have you tried?

Comment: @hakre im referring to the javascript of the page I load

Comment: @afuzzyllama there are no errors except for the fact that the javascript of the page loaded is not working

Comment: Where is `emaild` getting declared?  Is it getting set?  Does that emaild in combination with `posts.php?id=` actually yield anything when loading on its own?

Comment: You need to provide a better example, and it might be that what you try to do is not possible that way.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the content you're loading? When AJAX is used to load a page all <script> tags are stripped out and executed in the global scope by jQuery. So it could be a case of the scripts either a) not loading or b) not being executed the way you think they are.

Comment: When you say 'not working properly' do you mean 'not working' ?

Comment: What you are showing is partial. So it's hard to tell what's going on. But it sounds like you are loading the JS inside the DIV. If so, it sounds like you need to wrap this with $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem here:


      `div.html($("#load").load('posts.php?id='+emaild));`


$.html() expects an html string and you're giving it a deferred instead. It may not be the cause of your script not running, but good to eliminate anyhow.

Is there a reason why you're using $("#load").load when you want the output of the call to go inside div. In other words, isn't this what you really want?

      `div.load('posts.php?id=' + emaild);`